# survfit for stratified cox-model

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a stratified cox-model and want predicted survival-curves for certain profiles, based on that model.

Now, because I'm working with a large dataset with a lot of strata, I want predictions for very specific strata only, to save time and memory.

The help-page of `survfit.coxph` states:  *... If newdata does contain strata variables, then the result will contain one curve per row of newdata, based on the indicated stratum of the original model.*

When I run the code below, where newdata does contain the stratum-variable, I still get predictions for both strata, which contradicts the help-page

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = runif(200),
             X2 = sample(c("A", "B"), 200, replace = TRUE),
             Ev = sample(c(0,1), 200, replace = TRUE),
             Time = rexp(200))

testfit <- coxph( Surv(Time, Ev) ~ X1 + strata(X2), df)

out <- survfit(testfit, newdata = data.frame(X1 = 0.6, X2 = "A"))
```

Is there anything I fail to see or understand here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature in `survival:::survfit.coxph`. It looks like the intended behaviour in the code is that only requested strata are returned. In the function:

- `strata(X2)` is evaluated in an environment containing `newdata` and the result, `A` is returned.
- The full curve is then created.
- There is then some logic to `split` the curve into strata, but only if `result$surv` is a matrix.

In your example it is not a matrix. I can't find any documentation on the expected usage of this if it's not a bug. Perhaps it would be worth dropping the author/maintainer a note.

```
maintainer("survival")
# [1] "Terry M Therneau <xxxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxx.xxx>"
```

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a similar question on [survival's github](https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues/130)  that confirms it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks also for your contribution on github!

Answer (score 1):

Some comments that may be helpfull:

- My example was not big enough (and I seem not to have read the [related github post](https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues/130) very well, but that was after I posted my question here): if `newdata` has at least two lines (and of course the strata-variable), predictions are returned only for the requested strata
- There is an inefficiency inside `survfit.coxph`, where the baseline-hazard is calculated for every stratum in the original dataset, not only for the requested strata (see [my contribution to the same github post](https://github.com/therneau/survival/issues/130)). However, that doesn't seem to be a big issue (a test on a dataset with roughly half a million observation, 50% events and 1000 strata), takes less than a minute
- The problem is memory allocation somewhere during calculations (in the above example, things collapse once I want predictions for 100 observations - 1 stratum each - while the final output of predictions for 80 is only a few MB)
- My work-around:

  - Select all observations you want predictions for
  - use `lp <- predict(..., type='lp')` to get the linear predictor for all these observations
  - use survfit only on the first observation: `survfit(fit, newdata = expand_grid(newdf, strat = strata_list))`
  - Store the resulting survival estimates in a data.frame (or not, that's up to you)
  - To calculate predicted survival for other observations, use the PH-assumption (see formula below). This invokes the overhead of `survfit.coxph` only once and if you focus on survival on only a few times (e.g. 5- and 10-year survival), you can reduce the computer time even more

[image]